# Communications Site "News Post" option not available

Tags: office-365, modern-experience, communication-site

I have a communication site on **Tenant B** where on "+ New" button on home page doesn't have the usual options to create "News Post" or "News Link".  However on the other tenant **Tenant A**, if I create a communication site, it has the options are coming up.

Additionally the homepage has **"Promote"** option in **Tenant B**

Difference is given below.

[image]

Site was migrated from Tenant A to B.  With the promote option enabled, I believe SharePoint is not considering the page as Home page.

**Is there any setting that has to be enabled on tenant level to get these options?  Any pointers on this is appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. It`s some sort of a glitch with pages. Instructions below worked for me:

1. On your 'Tenant B' (which does not have the required options) create a NEW page, then go into site pages and set it as the new homepage.
2. Then reload the page you`re in and set the previous original home page back to being the actual home page again.
3. Now access your sites Home page and you should have all of the options there.

Hope this helps.